# Converting String array to java.util.List

Tags: java, arrays, collections

How do I convert a `String` array to a `java.util.List`?

Answer (score 289):

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"one", "two", "three"});
```

This is *a list view* of the array, the list is partly unmodifiable, you can't add or delete elements. But the time complexity is O(1).

If you want a modifiable a List:

```
List<String> strings = 
     new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"one", "two", "three"}));
```

This will copy all elements from the source array into a new list (complexity: O(n))

Answer (score 36):

Use the static `List list = Arrays.asList(stringArray)` or you could just iterate over the array and add the strings to the list.

Answer (score 23):

```
import java.util.Collections;

List myList = new ArrayList();
String[] myArray = new String[] {"Java", "Util", "List"};

Collections.addAll(myList, myArray);
```

Answer (score 15):

The Simplest approach:

```
String[] stringArray = {"Hey", "Hi", "Hello"};

List<String> list = Arrays.asList(stringArray);
```

Answer (score 8):

First Step you need to create a list instance through Arrays.asList();

```
String[] args = new String[]{"one","two","three"};
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(args);//it converts to immutable list
```

Then you need to pass 'list' instance to `new ArrayList();`

```
List<String> newList=new ArrayList<>(list);
```

Answer (score 6):

As of **Java 8** and Stream API you can use `Arrays.stream` and `Collectors.toList`:

```
String[] array = new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};
List<String> list = Arrays.stream(array).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is practical especially if you intend to perform further operations on the list.

```
String[] array = new String[]{"a", "bb", "ccc"};
List<String> list = Arrays.stream(array)
                          .filter(str -> str.length() > 1)
                          .map(str -> str + "!")
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

On Java 14 you can do this

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
```

Answer (score 1):

If the result should be a readonly list then you can use List.of(nameOfArray)

```
@Test
public void shouldMapArrayToList(){
    // given
    var testArray = new String[]{"1", "2", "3" };

    // when
    List<String> result = List.of(testArray);

    // then
    assertEquals("1", result.get(0));
    assertEquals("2", result.get(1));
    assertEquals("3", result.get(2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list like this: "one, two, three."

You can use this code :

```
  Arrays.asList(StringUtil.split("one, two, three",','))
```

**or**

```
    public static List<String> convertStringToList(String listAsString) {
    String[] list = listAsString.split("\\s*,\\s*");
    return Arrays.stream(list).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```