# How can I conver this string into a java list?

Tags: java, list, guava

How can I convert this string into a java list (java.util.List) of three elements ?

```
{Electronic,Pop,Rock}
```

I already use Google Guava, so that would be a good solution but I cant see one

Comment: Take a look at `java.util.Arrays`

Comment: What have you tired so far? Have you looked at https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained ?

Comment: I'm not sure why people vote this as too broad, since the answer is a short piece of code. And the question is not unclear at all. The problem here is that OP doesn't try anything to solve it (or at least OP doesn't show his/her efforts).

Comment: Is `{Electronic,Pop,Rock}` an array of Strings or one long String...?

Comment: Its one long String. I did try Arrays.asList() but that didn't work I just thought better to keep the question concise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
List<String> result = Splitter.on(CharMatcher.anyOf("{,}"))
                              .trimResults()
                              .omitEmptyStrings()
                              .splitToList();
```

Relevant documentation: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html

Comment: That feels pretty hacky. You're considering the braces as separators, though they're not. I'd suggest `Splitter.on(',').splitToList(s.substring(1, s.length - 1))`. Of course, it's far from perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array as displayed below.

```
     String sourceString = "{Electronic,Pop,Rock}";

   // it will remove curly braces
sourceString = sourceString.substring(1,sourceString.length()-1); 
    String[] arr = sourceString.split(",");
```

However you can use Array in place of List but if it is really necessary to make list then add following line.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
```

Comment: But it is a string, Im starting with a string containing that text not a literal, i cant assign String[] splits to a string; –  Paul Taylor 10 secs ago

Comment: @Paul Taylor Eairler I thought you have comma seperated string. I have changed the code to treat complete as a single String and then break it into parts to create a List of String. Comma ',' is used as seperator.

Answer (score 0):

Your List will be of type string so --> List< String > or you could use the ArrayList object.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026813/converting-string-array-to-java-util-list) question for pointers.

```
String tunes = "Electronic,Pop,Rock";
String[] splits = tunes.split(",");

List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(splits);
```

Comment: But it is a string, Im starting with a string containing that text not a literal, i cant assign String[] splits to a string;

Comment: @PaulTaylor, this should get you where you need to go

Comment: there are also {}'s, but thx anyway _ I was looking for a solution that recognized the input as a list _ I think I'll stick with the guava option