# Java List<string> not adding to list after Arrays.asList() has been used

Tags: java, arrays, string, list

I'm trying to do the following in Java:

```
String pageName = "MyPage";
String pageSpace= "SpaceA.SpaceB";
List<String> spaceList = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] spaceArr = pageSpace.split("\\.");
spaceList = Arrays.asList(spaceArr);
spaceList.add(pageName);
```

Why am I not able to add a string to the list? 
I can do spaceList.get(0) and spaceList.get(1) which returns "SpaceA" and "SpaceB" but spaceList.get(2) fails which should return "MyPage".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` returns a List of a fixed size that is backed by the array passed to it. You can't add/remove elements to/from that List.

You shouldn't even be able to reach the `spaceList.get(2)` statement, since `spaceList.add(pageName)` should throw `UnsupportedOperationException` first (perhaps you caught that exception).

To overcome that, create a new `ArrayList` :

```
spaceList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(spaceArr));
```

Answer (score 1):

To add more, `Arrays.asList` returns an `instance` of `AbstractList` with no `implementation` for `add` method, because of that you will recieve an `UnsupportedOperationException` from the `AbstractList`

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.asList` does not give you the instance of `java.util.ArrayList`, instead it gives the object of its own AbstractList implementation which is static inner class within Arrays class:

```
private static class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E> implements RandomAccess, Serializable { }
```

Though you can sort, iterate on the return List, it does not support add / remove kind of operations.

You might be looking for something discussed here : [Converting String array to java.util.List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026813/converting-string-array-to-java-util-list)